# How to return Age from Date and Time Field

Tags: sharepoint-online

We use SharePoint Online and need a simple way to display the age of our clients based on the entered birth date in a Date Time Field.  I have tried this "Work Around" https://abstractspaces.wordpress.com/2008/05/19/use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column with no luck.

Does anyone have a simple way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TRY THIS** on your Calculated Column Age

**=ROUND(((TODAY()-[Column Name])/365),0)&" Years"**

Comment: You are most welcome ;)

Comment: FYI - putting in date of birth as `01/07/1979` as at `13/04/2020` returns `41` (it should be `40`)